# Type bounds for unapplied type parameters

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types, type-bounds

How can I specify the bounds of an unapplied higher order type parameter, such that the following compiles:

```
trait Declr[Impl[_]]   // need to specify constraints for Impl's type parameter

trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]]

object X extends Declr[X]  // doesn't compile, because S is more strict
trait X[S <: Sys[S]]
```

Without adding more type parameters to `Declr`. Note that a solution is allowed to assume that the bound of `Impl`'s parameter is *always* `S <: Sys[S]` (i.e that is the bound for any type that can go into `Declr`).

I think I can write the constraint with a type *member* like this:

```
trait Declr {
  type Impl[S <: Sys[S]]
}

object X extends Declr {
  type Impl[S <: Sys[S]] = X[S]
}
trait X[S <: Sys[S]]
```

But how to do this as a type *parameter* (as the restatement of `type Impl` is very noisy, and I want to have `object X` as clean as possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not

```
trait Declr[Impl[S <: Sys[S]]]
trait Sys[ S <: Sys[ S ]]

object X extends Declr[ X ]  
trait X[ S <: Sys[ S ]]
```

Comment: I'm baffled. I'm sure I tried that and it didn't accept that first line. But obviously, now that I compile your code, it works :-# So sorry for the noise...